# HTTP Request works in browser but not in postman

Tags: http

Http request works in browser, i got 200 status, but not in postman or curl.I copied the request(all headers) from network tab of browser but got 403 response in postman.I also tried postman interceptor - same. What can be the reason ? How does the server understand that the request is not from the browser if i am sending the same request ?

here is request from browser(there is no any payload):

[image]

and from postman: [image]

Btw just curious

Comment: Can you share URL? and screen capture for browser and Postman.

Comment: @BenchVue shared, https://www.glassdoor.com/index.htm

Comment: Thanks, It forwarded to `https://www.glassdoor.com/Community/index.htm` and mine Postman got 200 OK too. I think mine's Postman picked up cookie due to logged in by my gmail account and glassdoor.com also logged same account.

Comment: @BenchVue the problem is that i do it in incognito, so without any cookies and without redirecting